# How to update tableview using javafx concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, background, javafx

**Everything work find when i run the code without background Thread(TASK CLASS)**

I want to update the tableview with the query results that the search method returns which is  **dataResource.search(parameters, sectionToRun)**

**Note: Everything is run under FXMLController**

This is code snippet below i'm using as the Task Thread:

```
@FXML
public TableView<Record> tblRecords; // i made this public so can access it
                                     // in the TACK CLASS

@FXML
private void onActionSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    ;
    final int sectionToRun; // This keep track of the part of the if branch
                            // of the query to execute

    String query = "";
    fullName = txtFullName.getText().trim();
    insurance = txtInsurance.getText().trim();
    age = txtAge.getText().trim();
    String day = cboSearchDay.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String month = cboSearchMonth.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String year = cboSearchYear.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    if (fullName.trim().isEmpty() && insurance.trim().isEmpty()) {
        lblSearchMessage
                .setText("Please enter a name or insurance number to search.");
        kit.beep();
        return;
    }

    // String dob = null;
    String date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

    if (!insurance.isEmpty()) {

        sectionToRun = 1; // query 1

        parameters.put("insuranceId", insurance);

    } else if (!fullName.isEmpty() && !age.isEmpty()
            && CalendarUtil.parse(date) != null) {

        parameters.put("name", fullName);
        parameters.put("dob", dob);

        sectionToRun = 2; // query 2

    } else if (!fullName.isEmpty() && !age.isEmpty()
            && CalendarUtil.parse(date) == null) {

        parameters.put("name", fullName);
        parameters.put("age", age);

        sectionToRun = 3; // query 3

    } else if (!fullName.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty()
            && CalendarUtil.parse(date) != null) {

        parameters.put("name", fullName);
        parameters.put("dob", dob);

        sectionToRun = 4; // query 4
    } else if (!fullName.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty()
            && CalendarUtil.parse(date) == null) {

        parameters.put("name", fullName);

        sectionToRun = 5; // query 5
    } else {
        lblSearchMessage
                .setText("Please provide at least patient name or insurance ID number to search");
        return;
    }

    final Task task = new Task<ObservableList<Record>>() {
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Record> call() throws InterruptedException {
            updateMessage("Finding Records . . .");

            List<Record> records = dataResource.search(parameters,
                    sectionToRun); // search query method
            updateMessage("Finished.");

            return FXCollections.observableArrayList(records);
        }

    };
    progressIndicator.disableProperty().set(false);
    iblStatus.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    btnSearch.disableProperty().bind(task.onRunningProperty());
    tblRecords.itemsProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());
    progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    task.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(
                ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue,
                Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                if (btnSearch.isDisabled()) {
                    btnSearch.disableProperty().set(false);
                    progressIndicator.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    new Thread(task).start();
    // end of the code snippet
}
```

When i run get the following exception below:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.keyReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:147)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.callAction(ButtonBehavior.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:121)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase$1.handle(BehaviorBase.java:119)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3513)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$2300(Scene.java:3472)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:1904)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2270)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:136)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:100)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:163)
```

Please can anyone tell me what wrong the code.

Comment: Can you update the question to show more of the context? In particular, the `tblRecords` field (which does not need to be public) is presumably an instance field in the controller; but where is the rest of the code? It should be in the handler method for some action referenced in the FXML. The error seems to indicate that method can't be run by reflection, so perhaps you forgot to annotate it with `@FXML`?

Comment: Hi @James_D, thank u for your quick responses, i have added all the necessary codes to it for you to check for me and i have annotate all my controls including the tableView which is the tblRecords in code(FXMLController).

Comment: I don't understand how `btnSearch.disableProperty().bind(task.onRunningProperty());` can compile: `onRunningProperty` is not a `BooleanProperty`.